# SQL error when selecting column named YEAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a column named "YEAR" from a table.

I can achieve this using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (mybook, 'SELECT mytable.year FROM mytable')
```

but not when I use this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (mybook, 'SELECT year FROM mytable')
```

Is this because "year" is some sort of reserved word or is there another reason?

Comment: There are two servers involved. Clearly you are running from SQL Server (which version?) - we also need to know where `mybook` is pointing to (database system & version)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server, `Year` is a reserved word.  So it will complain when you try to use it.

If you are using MySql, you can use back ticks (`) around year.

In SQL Server, you can use `[]`'s around `year`, `[year]`.

**EDIT**

After seeing your updated question, the following SQL should work:

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (mybook, 'SELECT [year] FROM mytable')`

Comment: I think you're right with your reason but your solution was not working... I've updated the query to show how it is actually used with OPENQUERY...

Comment: @Tom - you need to qualify the field either with the DB name/schema format (Database.dbo.table) or using the SQL Server name character which is the square bracket `[]`

Comment: This is voted up so much?? It is a falsehood. SQL Server has NEVER baulked at year without quotes. It is reserved, but not protected. I just verified with an OPENQUERY and it worked as is with `select year from mytable`

Answer (score 4):

use

```
SELECT [year] FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [year] FROM mytable
```

Use brackets around the field name